# Can we have wireframes? Like on UX.SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

One thing I really like on UX.SE is that you can add a quick sketch to your question or answer that shows what you thought about, what to expect, etc.

In WordPress we often have that need, but need to figure it out by sketching up MockUps, make UI collages or other stuff.

> [image]

Could we please have wireframes? At least for a test run to see if it really is necessary (from the amount of questions/answers that might need it)?

Comment: what would we need it for? p.s its awesome :)

Comment: For wireframing solutions? ;)

Comment: I don't see that wireframe button on ux.stackexchange.com ..?

Comment: Maybe you need more privileges?